# Django Abstract Class change behaviour according to actual class

Tags: django, class, django-models, django-model-field

I think following code explains what I'm trying to do

```
from django.db import models


class MyBaseClass(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.type = #What Should I write here?#
        self.type = self.class.type ?
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Model1(MyBaseClass):
    TYPE = 1


class Model2(MyBaseClass):
    TYPE = 2
```

I want to make sure following assertions work:

```
instance1 = Model1.objects.create()
assert(instance1.type, 1)
instance2 = Model2.objects.create()
assert(instance1.type, 2)
```

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: What is the use of `TYPE` here? Is this just a static aspect, or do you want to set a *default* value. If it is the former, you should *never* define a `type` column in the first place, since then the records of the two models are stored in *different* tables, so it has no use at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setting the *default* value of inherited models

If you want to *set* the default of the inherited models, you can monkey patch these. Like:

```
class Model1(MyBaseClass):
    TYPE = 1


class Model2(MyBaseClass):
    TYPE = 2

Model1._meta.get_field('type').default = Model1.TYPE
Model2._meta.get_field('type').default = Model2.TYPE
```

## Adding a static attribute to the models

In case the `.type` of all `Model1` objects is *always* `1`, and for `Model2` objects it is always `2`, then there is no reason at all to store these types in the database. These models are stored in different tables, hence the fact that a record originates from the `app_model1` table "implies" that. In that case, you thus can set a class attribute, like:

```
class MyBaseClass(models.Model):
    type = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Model1(MyBaseClass):
    type = 1


class Model2(MyBaseClass):
    type = 2
```

Comment: Very insightful comment and answer, I actually wanted to do some extra logic based on the `type`, but after sleeping on it I realized I can just put the extra logic in a function and in both .save() methods I can call it with different parameters.

Your answer is still very useful.